# How to combine pdf when one pdf file is stored on s3 bucket using combine pdf gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, amazon-s3

In my `task` table I can access pdf file `@task&.assignable&.pdf_file` that is stored on s3 bucket.
I can access to its url using `@task&.assignable&.pdf_file.file.url`

I want to add a new page in the same pdf file so I am using [combine_pdf gem](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf/). It is getting path of `file1` that I have generated with `wicked_pdf` but on line

```
pdf << CombinePDF.load(@task&.assignable&.pdf_file.file.url)
```

It is showing error:

**No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://patientiq1.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/ < hashed_path >.pdf? < access_key >**

```
file1_path = Rails.root.join('tmp', filename)
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
  render_to_string('patient_engagements/signed_page', layout: 'pdf', locals: { :@signed_pdf => @signed_pdf })
)
File.open(file1_path, 'wb') do |file|
  file << pdf
end

pdf = CombinePDF.new
pdf << CombinePDF.load(file1_path) # one way to combine, very fast.
pdf << CombinePDF.load(@task&.assignable&.pdf_file.file.url)
pdf.save "combined.pdf"
```

Comment: Could you please accept the answer? I asume you accept my answer as correct (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994433/store-combined-pdf-combined-by-combine-pdf-gem) so, accept it, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use load with remote files, use [parse](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf/blob/ef07183d1dbbfc64a2db71c29dc13416d3504fd6/lib/combine_pdf/api.rb#L38) instead

```
require 'combine_pdf'
require 'net/http'

url = "https://example.com/my.pdf"
pdf = CombinePDF.parse Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body
```

Extracted from [Loading and parsing DPF data](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf/blob/master/README.md#loading-and-parsing-pdf-data) at CombinePDF docs.