# Store combined pdf combined by combine_pdf gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation

I have combined two `pdf` files as follows

```
pdf = CombinePDF.new
pdf << CombinePDF.parse(Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(@task.assignable.pdf_file.try(:file).try(:url))).body, allow_optional_content: true)
pdf << CombinePDF.load(file1_path) # one way to combine, very fast.
pdf.save "combined.pdf"
```

I can check and see my combined file by downloading as follows:

```
send_data pdf.to_pdf, filename: "combined.pdf", type: "application/pdf"
```

This all working fine but I want to store this pdf in `@signed_pdf` record.

It is allowing to to store the pdf in my record as follow:

```
@signed_pdf.signed_file = pdf.to_pdf
```

but it seems not to good approach. I want to store it as object.

```
@signed_pdf.signed_file = pdf
```

but in this case using `@signed_pdf.signed_file.to_pdf` for downloading purpose or any other purpose showing the error:

```
undefined method `to_pdf' for "#<CombinePDF::PDF:0x000000000dabd5d0>":String Did you mean? to_f to_d
```

What would be the beeter way to store `combined pdf` in my record?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to store the pdf on files system or a block storage provider (Amazon S3) and save the path to the db instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to parse string first?

```
CombinePDF.parse(@signed_pdf.signed_file).to_pdf
```